# Dreamweaver as web programming software. Good?

Tags: dreamweaver

I use Dreamweaver for HTML, PHP, CSS, and JS. I like how it keeps my files organized and auto completes basic code. Should I stick with Dreamweaver or progress using a different software?

Comment: WYSIWYG editors == pain.

Comment: @Juliet : Dreamweaver has a non-WYSIWYG editing mode that's pretty acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work as a freelance, or are given free choice of your editor, stick with whatever floats your boat. If Dreamweaver is enough for you, keep it.

Most PHP shops I know of have their developers use Zend Studio, the Eclipse PHP plugin, and sometimes Netbeans. If you're looking for a future job at one of these places, trying out one of these editors might be interesting - and you might discover features that Dreamweaver does not have, such as a PHP debugger.

Try doing a small one-weekend project with another editor, explicitly trying not to use it as you would use Dreamweaver.

Comment: +1 for recommending getting familiar with other editors as well!

Answer (score 1):

Where do you plan to progress to?  Newer style stuff like JSF separates the presentation from the code, so you can pick different tools for doing the web site and the code.  I've been trying out Fireworks into Dreamweaver to do the design and Netbeans to do the code with decent success so far.  Usually tools are oriented either toward the designer or the coder so none of them do both jobs equally well.  Even though I use netbeans, most my heavy editing is in emacs.  GUI editors tend to be rather clunky and slow.

Comment: I just want to adapt to one editor.

Answer (score 1):

Iam use PhpStorm by JetBrains and have a licence, it's fast enough if compare with Eclipse but written on the Java too

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver is awesome, does many things very well, is almost the best in  some key areas, WYSIWYG for designers, and a coding tool for developers. I used to consider it the best, but PHPStorm has opened my eyes when it came to PHP development.  Automatic refracting is one is it's key benefits.  Refracting is breaking up code into reusable code, basically it writes methods for you! It also allows collapsing of any set of {}'s (dreamweaver can't). I did, however found that some settings are clumsy and it doesn't have custom snippets like DW. In the future I will be using this and DW for a double sworded slicing of projects!